# Array/Hash manipulations with RXJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

As I'm quite new to Observables and RXJS I would like to ask a question:
What is the best method of emulating Hash/Array manipulations, such as adding and removing items from the Hash/Array?

I have this following code snippet that works as expected but is probably not following the Observable "way":

```js
var newMessage = new Rx.Subject(),
  removeMessage = new Rx.Subject(),
  sortMessages = new Rx.Subject(),
  messages = Rx.Observable.merge(
    newMessage.map(function(x) {
      return {
        action: 'add',
        value: x
      };
    }),
    removeMessage.map(function(x) {
      return {
        action: 'remove',
        value: x
      };
    }),
    sortMessages.map(function(x) {
      return {
        action: 'sort',
        value: true
      };
    })
  )
  .scan(function(acc, operation) {
    switch (operation.action) {
      case 'add':
        acc.push(operation.value);
        break;
      case 'remove':
        var removeIndex = acc.indexOf(operation.value);
        if (removeIndex !== -1) {
          acc.splice(removeIndex, 1);
        }
        break;
      case 'sort':
        acc.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a > b;
        });
        break;
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);

var subscription = messages.subscribe(
  function(x) {
    console.log('next ' + x);
  },
  function(err) {
    console.log('Error: %s', err);
  },
  function() {
    console.log('Completed');
  });

newMessage.onNext(4);
newMessage.onNext(2);
newMessage.onNext(1);
removeMessage.onNext(2);
removeMessage.onNext(1);
newMessage.onNext(3);
sortMessages.onNext(true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/4.0.1/rx.all.js"></script>
```

I want to be able to push notifications of arbitrary types (add,remove,sort,find) via various Subjects and retrieve the final result, which is the sum of all past instructions I've already committed (without the stream to go through all the instructions from the beginning, which is bad performance).

It seems much simpler when doing is the classical way with arrays and hashes, but there must be a proper method with Observables, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've encontered this [Angular2-rxjs-chat](https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat/blob/master/app/ts/services/MessagesService.ts) demo that does exactly what I was looking for in a very elegant way.

To make it short, they use streams of actions or operations (insert, mark, etc.) each of which is a Subject, that are invoked inside a scan Observable and alter the last state of the list.

This is done in the most flat and generic way. 
Way to go!

Comment: I believe this file is now located here:
https://github.com/ng-book/angular2-rxjs-chat/blob/master/src/app/message/messages.service.ts